# Variable of state update on LayersControl.Overlay checkbox toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

This question is on asking information. 
I went through [LayersControl.Overlay](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#layerscontrol) Documentation, 
At the usage of this snippet,

```
<LayersControl.Overlay name="Marker with popup">
    <Marker position={[51.51, -0.06]}>
      <Popup>
        <span>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </span>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  </LayersControl.Overlay>
```

This snippet generates the checkbox in `LayersControl` stackbox with name `Marker with popup`
On ticking the `Marker with popup` checkbox, it pops out the `marker` in the given position.

Here, I want to update a `boolean` in `state` on toggling the value of checkbox.
On removing the `Marker` code inside and adding a state change condition in the  below snippet,

```
<LayersControl.Overlay name="Marker with popup">
    { this.setState({ variableToBeChanged : true }) };
  </LayersControl.Overlay>
```

Instead, On adding this, the checkbox disappears from the stackbox.

So, can you please tell how to place such condition inside this `Overlay` component without disappearance of checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to understand how react-leaflet works - it's just wrapper over Leaflet.js. So in some cases you can't directly control UI elements and their behaviour.
In these case you can only toggle checkbox throw Leaflet control
and then listen what happens like

```
 //If you turn on layer
 map.on('overlayadd', this.setState({ variableToBeChanged : true }));
 //If you turn off layer
 map.on('overlayremove', this.setState({ variableToBeChanged : false }));
```